# Sql Server - Does order of fields in the select clause or the on clause within inner join matters

Tags: sql-server

I am a beginner with sql joins and trying to understand the various types of joins in sql server. My query pertains to the following two pieces of code which I have just typed out in sql server 2012 using the AdventureWorks2008 database. However code piece one just takes a very long time (I've kept it executing for about 45 mins now) with no resultset. However code piece two runs very quickly in a flash and outputs the resultset. I'm just confused as to what is the issue.

Here is the code.

code piece one..(this one takes a very long time executing with no resultset)

```
select 
pro.ProductID
,pro.Name
,soh.OrderDate
,soh.SalesOrderID
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
inner join Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod on sod.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
inner join  Production.Product pro on pro.ProductID = sod.ProductID
order by soh.SalesOrderID
```

Code piece two (this one runs quickly)

```
`select soh.SalesOrderId
       ,soh.orderDate
       ,p.ProductId
       ,p.name
 from sales.SalesOrderHeader as soh
 inner join sales.SalesOrderDetail as sod on soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
 inner join Production.Product as p on sod.ProductID = p.ProductID
 order by soh.SalesOrderId`
```

Any help/hints is appreciated. I've researched all of the stackoverflow's previous questions but haven't found any straight answer as to whether the ordering of the fields is responsible for slow query execution or the ordering of the join clause is responsible. Also I've read that the query plan optimiser has something to do as to which is the best plan for a query execution however I have failed to rationalize in my code pieces context.

Comment: I suspect you have an interfering external process, likely holding a lock. There is no reason for performance of these two queries to differ by an iota. Run them sequentially, with no other activity to the DB server, to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for your response. After reading your response, I have tried to run the sp_who2 to see any blocking. But I could'nt find any. Also I've tried closing down SSMS and opening a new query window to execute. But it's just the same. Also I do not have any SSMS window opened in edit mode. I'm nowhere editing any of the tables just querying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with your join to `SalesOrderDetail` in the first query. You're using the `sod` table alias for both fields in your join. One of those should be `soh`. Having the table aliases being wrong like that causes a cross join which will produce an enormous recordset.

Comment: Cross join rather than full outer join though.

Comment: +1 I was even looking for something like that and missed it. I must need new glasses.